# Scheme-theoric inclusion v.s. topological inclusion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $X$ can be written as $X=X_1\cup X_2$, where $X_i$ are both unions of irreducible components of $X$ and have no common component.

Now given a closed subscheme $Y\subset X$. Assume that $|Y|\subset |X_2|$, i.e. $Y$ is contained in $X_2$ as topological spaces. Then my question is

> Is it always true that $Y\subset X_2$ as schemes? If it is not true in general, then what assumption do we need?

Since $|Y|\subset |X_2|$, we have $Y_{red}\subset X_{2~red}$. For the case $Y$ is reduced, we know $Y=Y_{red}\subset X_{2~red}\subset X_2$. Is the statement still true when $Y$ is not reduced? For example, is it true under the assumption that $Y,X_1,X_2$ are all Cohen-Macaulay?

I have tried to work out the simplest case. Assume that $Y=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ has only two components, i.e. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are irreducible. Then $X_i=V(q_i)$, where $q_i$ are primary ideals and $p_i:=\sqrt{q_i}$ are minimal prime ideals. And we have $q_1\cap q_2=(0)$. Assume that $Y=V(I)$, then by assumptions we have $q_2\subset p_2\subset \sqrt{I}$. Since $q_2$ are finitely generated, we can find an integer $n$ such that $q_2^n\subset I$. But I'm not sure how to show $n=1$...

Comment: [Scheme-theoretic image](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01R5). With a quasicompactness hypothesis, the scheme-theoretic image is the closure of the set-theoretic image. You might also need [lemma 26.12.7](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0356) on the reduced subscheme structure.

Comment: @DavidLui "the scheme-theoretic image is the closure of the set-theoretic image" is missing a few words - should be more like "the underlying set of the scheme theoretic image is the closure of the set-theoretic image". But the general advice of "everything works for varieties with no funny business" is correct. (Good pointer to the correct device to solve the problem!)

Comment: @DavidLui Thanks! Yes, when $Y$ is reduced, your argument gives a positive answer. I'm wondering that is there any generalisation when $Y$ is non-reduced? The concrete situation I meet is that, $Y,X_1,X_2$ are all Cohen-Macaulay and $\dim X_1=\dim Y=1$, $\dim X_2=2$.

Comment: [Quasi-reposted on MO with answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432362/a-question-on-curves-on-effective-divisors).